# Stereo convolution with AudioKit

Tags: convolution, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit (version 4.10.1) to apply reverberation to a microphone signal. I just started experimenting with AKConvolution with a stereo impulse response (.wav file) applied to the microphone signal. My code is functioning with no errors, but the resulting reverberation is mono, rather than stereo. Applying AKZitaReverb to the same microphone signal produces nice, stereo reverb, so I expected AKConvolution with a stereo impulse response to do the same. I think stereo (2-channel) convolution should be possible, but I am not super-familiar with AudioKit. I think the microphone signal channel is stereo (I set AKSettings.channelCount = 2).  Seems like a stereo signal convolved with a stereo impulse response should produce stereo reverb.

I am stuck, and would appreciate any ideas you might have to get me unstuck. Before posting this message, I searched online for other people who've encountered the same problem, but similar posts are all a few years old and the solutions people suggested included links that are now dead and/or depended on classes and functions that are no longer part of more recent versions of AudioKit.

Thanks!